# Group by true or false in several groups

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following class:

- Id int
- Active bool
- DateTime datetime
- Approved bool

I have the list of that class similar to this:

- **Id** 1  **Active** true  **Approved** true
- **Id** 2  **Active** true  **Approved** true
- **Id** 3  **Active** true  **Approved** true
- **Id** 4  **Active** true  **Approved** false
- **Id** 5  **Active** true  **Approved** false
- **Id** 6  **Active** true  **Approved** false
- **Id** 7  **Active** true  **Approved** true
- **Id** 8  **Active** true  **Approved** true
- **Id** 9  **Active** true  **Approved** false

I want to get items from list group by **Approved** but i want grouped objects to be in this order:

- **True** all objects till first false.
- **False** all objects till next true.
- **True** all objects till next false.
- **False** all objects till next true.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide your desired result? What means: _"True all objects till first false."_? What bool do you mean and what means first/next?

Comment: First to get all objects where **Approved** is true until the first false. Next to get all object where **Approved** is false until the next true. And so on

Comment: So is it not possible to edit your question and add a desired result? Your comment makes no sense. You want all approved, then all not approved, then the next true and so on??? (What **`True`**? You have two bools in  your class, that was the reason i've asked it in my previous comment )

Comment: I want all approved from Id 1 to Id 3. Then all disapproved from Id 4 to Id 6. Again all approved from Id 7 to Id 8, and all disapproved etc. Id 9. Now i think it is more clear

Comment: Ok, but that is exactly the order of your source list. So either your example is bad or you have showed your desired result as starting point. Or is your desired result 4 groups (in this example) where the elements are ordered by (datetime or id?)?

Comment: I want to group(in this example in 4 groups) ordered by Id, but i want to put all 4 groups in one list.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use TakeWhile method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534804(v=vs.95).aspx

I'm not very good in LINQ but this code should work. This principle also could be extended not only for booleans, but for any type which supports IEqualityComparer

```
var list = new List<Test>();
list.Add(new Test(1, true, true));
list.Add(new Test(2, true, true));
list.Add(new Test(3, true, true));
list.Add(new Test(4, true, false));
list.Add(new Test(5, true, false));
list.Add(new Test(6, true, false));
list.Add(new Test(7, true, true));
list.Add(new Test(8, true, true));
list.Add(new Test(9, true, false));

var listTemp = list;
var result = new List<Tuple<bool, List<Test>>>();

while (listTemp.Count > 0)
{
    var approved = listTemp[0].Approved;
    var tuple = new Tuple<bool, List<Test>>(approved, listTemp.TakeWhile(x => approved == x.Approved).ToList());
    result.Add(tuple);
    listTemp = listTemp.SkipWhile(x => approved == x.Approved).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var data = list.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
bool approved = data.First().Approved;
var groups = new List<Tuple<bool, List<Foo>>>();
var all = groups.SelectMany(x => x.Item2);

while (all.Count() != list.Count())
{
    groups.Add(
        Tuple.Create(
            approved
            , list.Skip(all.Count())
                  .TakeWhile(x => x.Approved == approved)
                  .ToList()));
    approved = !approved;
}

foreach (var grp in groups)
{
    Console.Write("Next block: {0} with {1} elements", grp.Item1, grp.Item2.Count);
}
```

Here's your class:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
}
```

and sample data:

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 1, Active = true, Approved = true });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 2, Active = true, Approved = true });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 3, Active = true, Approved = true });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 4, Active = true, Approved = false });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 5, Active = true, Approved = false });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 6, Active = true, Approved = false });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 7, Active = true, Approved = true });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 8, Active = true, Approved = true });
list.Add(new Foo() { Id = 9, Active = true, Approved = false });
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this solution helps me to understand the Tuple class